# .htaccess image redirect

Tags: php, image, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've written a PHP class to add a watermark to an image, it works great when accessed via URL directly. I would like to "redirect" every image to my URL like so:

```
http://www.mysite.com/img.jpg
```

to this

```
http://www.mysite.com/watermark/watermark.php?image=http://www.mysite.com/img.jpg
```

Basically what I want is to pass the src attribute specified in the HTML to the image variable. I'm currently struggling with my `.htaccess` file and I can't get it working, here it is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^_].*\.(gif|jpg|png))$ /watermark/watermark.php?image=$1 [L]
```

Looking forward to your replies and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$ watermark/watermark.php?image=$1.$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it's no go.

Comment: @phil you are right, i actually just found an error in my code too, thanks

Comment: you have other rules in your .htaccess that can conflict with this one?

Comment: I don't think so, I have this at the top: <Limit GET POST>
 require valid-user
</Limit>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "/www/URL"
AuthUserFile /path/file.passwd

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5974/discussion-between-book-of-zeus-and-skatebail)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-MultiViews` to your options line, so it reads as:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```